# How to test Sign Up API (Post Method) for multiple users in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, test-design, load-testing, performance-testing

I tried multiple `user sign ups` using `Sign-up API` (`POST` Method) with parameterization. But It's not working.

1. I have set the `CSV Data` set `Config`
   [image]
2. Added the variable names in `Param` value
   [image]
3. Added a `HTTP Header Manager` to define the content type (`application/json`)
   [image]
4. My `CSV` sheet:
   [image]
5. Added `Cookie Manager`:
   [image]
6. The error shows `Param not found`
   [image]
7. Output in `Debug Sampler`:
   [image]

[image]

Will be much appreciated If anyone could help me find the mistake I am making. I am new to JMeter so It's fairly possible I am missing out something.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema), it might be the case that your API treats the request body as the plain text hence cannot parse the provided data.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Can you please tell me how to do that? I mean sharing a short example/reference would be great!
Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
In step-3 (Shared the screenshot) I did the same.
But, If I need to configure anything there further, Can you please tell me how to do that? I mean sharing a short example/reference would be great!
Thank you.
Thank you.